# Use template layout for list elements in ASP.NET for results from jquery API call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my cshtml, I have a list where each entry has the same complex style (simplified here for brevity):

```
@model List<string>
<h1>List</h1>
<ul id="container">
   @foreach (var entry in Model)
   {
      <li>
         <div>
            <h2>@entry</h2>
            <p>Some content</p>
         </div>
      </li>
   }
</ul>
```

Now suppose the list is the result of a long running API call. I can add

```
@section Scripts
{
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $.getJSON('api/getlist', function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
               $("#container").append('<li><div><h2>' + item + '</h2><p>Some content</p></div></li>');
            });
         });
      });
   </script>
}
```

This, in my opinion, is awful, as the layout now is embedded in JS, obscured as a string (which makes it difficult to spot errors).
What I much rather would like to have is a cshtml file with the layout of each list element, i.e.

```
@model string
<li>
   <div>
      <h2>@Model</h2>
      <p>Some content</p>
   </div>
</li>
```

I didn't find any way to adjust the javascript to take the html code from another file and fill in the data from the returned json. Is there any way to properly separate those UI elements (i.e. container in a separate file from the entry element)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to include that 'template' in your view as a partial view (inside a hidden container), that you can clone and append to the DOM. For example (and assuming its named `_Template.cshtml`)

```
<div id="template" hidden>
    @Html.Partial("_Template");
</div>
```

Then in the script you can clone it, update its contents, and append it to the DOM, for example

```
var template = $('#template');
var container = $("#container") // cache it
$.getJSON('api/getlist', function (result) {
    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
        var clone = template.clone(); // copy it
        clone.find('h2').text(item); // update
        container.append(clone.html()); // add it
    });
});
```

If the 'template' is more complex, you might give appropriate elements class names to make selecting the appropriate element easier (i.e. `clone.find('.someClassName')`)

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this works. However, this leaves the action of filling all the fields in the UI element to a piece of JS code separate from the UI control. Is there any way to leave this responsibility to the cshtml with typed model?

Comment: Not if you want to fill the values from json. You could of course make it all strongly typed by having the controller method return a partial view (based on `@model List<string>` containing the html for each item in a model and append it to the container